# derivation of activity coefficient from Margules laws?

Tags: physical-chemistry, mixtures

**basics**

In Margules activity model, the excess Gibbs free energy is expressed as:

$$
\frac{G^{ex}}{RT}=X_1 X_2 (A_{21} X_1 +A_{12} X_2) + X_1^2 X_2^2 (B_{21}X_1+ B_{12} X_2) + ...  
$$

meanwhile, we know the relationship between activity coefficients of components and the excess Gibbs is:

$$
G^{ex} = RT(X_1 \ln \gamma_1 + X_2 \ln \gamma_2)
$$

and based on the above, I see many conclusions give:

$$
 \ln\ \gamma_1=[A_{12}+2(A_{21}-A_{12})x_1]x^2_2
\\ \ln\ \gamma_2=[A_{21}+2(A_{12}-A_{21})x_2]x^2_1
$$

which would be the result of partial differential of equation1 with respect to $X_1$，$X_2$ separately.

**But how?**

take $X_2$ for example, and only consider the first item.

shouldn't it be:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (G^{ex} / RT)}{\partial X_2} = \ln \gamma_2 &= \frac{\partial \{X_1 X_2 (A_{21} X_1 +A_{12} X_2) \}}{\partial X_2} \\
&= A_{21}X_1^2 + 2 A_{12} X_1X_2
\end{align*}
$$

???

can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is fine, but you are partially differentiating incorrectly, watch the definition for the natural logarithm of the activity coefficient

\begin{align}
  \ln(\gamma_1) 
  & = \bigg[\dfrac{\partial(nG^E)}{\partial n_1}\bigg]_{P,T,n_2} \\
  & = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial n_1} \bigg\{n\bigg[\frac{n_1n_2}{n^2}\bigg(A_{21}\frac{n_1}{n} + A_{12}\frac{n_2}{n}\bigg)\bigg]\bigg\} \\
  & = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial n_1} \bigg[\frac{n_1n_2}{n^2}
(A_{21}n_1 + A_{12}n_2)\bigg] \\
  & = \dfrac{n_2n^2 - 2nn_1n_2}{n^4}(A_{21}n_1 + A_{12}n_2) + A_{21}\frac{n_1n_2}{n^2} \\
  & = \dfrac{n_2n - 2n_1n_2}{n^3}(A_{21}n_1 + A_{12}n_2) + A_{21}x_1x_2 \\
  & = \dfrac{n_2 ( n - 2n_1)}{n^2}\bigg(\frac{A_{21}n_1 + A_{12}n_2}{n}\bigg) + A_{21}x_1x_2 \\
  & = x_2(1 - 2x_1)(A_{21}x_1 + A_{12} x_2) + A_{21}x_1x_2 \\
  & = x_2 [(1 - 2x_1)(A_{21}x_1 + A_{12} x_2) + A_{21}x_1] \\
  & = x_2 [2A_{21}x_1 + A_{12}x_2 - 2A_{21}x_1^2 - 2A_{12}x_1x_2 ] \\
  & = x_2 [2A_{21}x_1 - 2A_{21}x_1^2 + A_{12}x_2 - 2A_{12}x_1x_2 ] \\
  & = x_2 [2A_{21}x_1(1 - x_1) + A_{12}x_2 - 2A_{12}x_1x_2 ] \\
  & = x_2 (2A_{21}x_1x_2 + A_{12}x_2 - 2A_{12}x_1x_2) \\
  & = x_2^2 (2A_{21}x_1 + A_{12} - 2A_{12}x_1) \rightarrow
 \boxed{\ln(\gamma_1) = x_2^2[A_{12} + 2(A_{21} - A_{12})x_1]}
\end{align}